# Inject formula in row below blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet structured with pricing in Column U. I want to inject new pricing formula into the first row of each sub table within this worksheet (where column E reads "Gallons - New Bdgt"). The structure is the same for the entire worksheet.
[My worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkuvO.png)

Here is my VBA attempt

```
Sub FillFormulas()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("U:U").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    With r
        .Offset(-1, 0).Formula = "=XLOOKUP(D2,'2021 Pricing'!$C$6:$C$47,'2021 Pricing'!$K$6:$K$47,""Not Found"",0)"
    End With
End Sub
```

This is not working, any advice?

Comment: What does your subroutine returns as "not working result"? If you want to target the first row of each sub-table, shouldn't it be `.Offset(1,0)`? I also guess that `D2` isn't supposed to stay D2, right? You need it to become D10, D18, and so on, right?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey "Not working" is not throwing an error nor making obvious progress. Now, I see that I offset in the wrong direction. (－‸ლ)
Yes, D2 is dynamic. It seems to be functioning properly. Thank you again.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is solved or that the dynamic D2 reference is working and you still need assistance?

Comment: It is resolved.